# How to test a socketConnection under Windows?

Tags: r, windows, networking

I have implemented the client protocol for BaseX (an open source XML-database) in a R-package (RBaseX). The people from CRAN asked me to add `testthat`-tests to the sources, and thanks to those tests I discovered (and fixed) some bugs.

The package has been developed on a linux-client. BaseX was also installed on the client.
When no basexserver is running, all tests should fail. Therefore every `test_that`-section starts with a call to the following function which tests if a socketConnection can be created:

```
skip_unless_socket_available <- function() {
    tryCatch({
    sock <- base::socketConnection(
      host = "localhost", 1984,
      open = "w+b", server = FALSE, blocking = TRUE, encoding = "utf-8")
    close(sock)
    TRUE
  }, error = function(e) {
    skip(paste0("basexserver not available:\n'", conditionMessage(e), "'"))
  })
}
```

On a linux- or a Windows client, with a running basexserver available, `test_check("RBaseX")` terminates without errors. When no basexserver is available, on a linux-client `test_check("RBaseX")` also terminates without errors.
But a Windows-client hangs without returning errors or warnings.

What is the correct way to test in Windows if a socketConnection can be created that connects to a server?

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Windows and linux behave different when there is no response from the resource at all.  When using linux and when calling 'socketConnection' without an explicit timeout-setting, the call is terminated immediately.
In Windows, it is necessary to provide a timeout-value. 'timeout = 1' solved my problem.

Ben